# How can I convert Chinese characters into another set?

Tags: translation

I'm trying to reproduce a character conversion...

Essentially out of the Chinese word for Login. In this example the Chinese word for Login, "登录"should be converted into this text instead "µÇÂ¼".

It would be nice if there was a piece of software that did this for me already...

Comment: `>>> print u'登录'.encode('gbk').decode('latin1')`
`µÇÂ¼`

Comment: Great I'll give it a try, do you know of a text editor that would do this automatically by chance?

Comment: Nope. But `iconv` will do it to entire text files.

Comment: What language was your code written in? I'm using C++.

Comment: Python. With C++ you'll have to use something like ICU.

Comment: I wouldn't mind writing it in the conversion in Python, but when I test it on an online python terminal I get this error.. Non-ASCII character '\xe7' in file main.py on line 3, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details       
sh-4.3$ python main.py

Comment: Did you read the article at that URL?

Comment: Yes results in this error... UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-3: ordinal not in range(128)